# Array of pointers from C++ to NumPy through Cython

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, cython

I have a library in c++ and I'm trying to wrap it for python using Cython. One function returns an array of 3D vectors (float (*x)[3]) and I want to access that data from python. I was able to do so by doing something like

```
res = [
    (self.thisptr.x[j][0],self.thisptr.x[j][1],self.thisptr.x[j][2])
    for j in xrange(self.natoms)
]
```

but I would like to access this as a numpy array, so I tried numpy.array on that and it was much slower. I also tried

```
        cdef np.ndarray res = np.zeros([self.thisptr.natoms,3], dtype=np.float)
        cdef int i
        for i in range(self.natoms):
            res[i][0] = self.thisptr.x[i][0]
            res[i][1] = self.thisptr.x[i][1]
            res[i][2] = self.thisptr.x[i][2]
```

But is about three times slower than the list version.

Any suggestions on how to convert the list of vectors to an numpy array faster?

The complete code is

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


ctypedef np.float_t ftype_t
cdef extern from "ccxtc.h" namespace "ccxtc":
    cdef cppclass xtc:
        xtc(char []) except +
        int next()
        int natoms
        float (*x)[3]
        float time


cdef class pyxtc:
    cdef xtc *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, char fname[]):
        self.thisptr = new xtc(fname)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    property natoms:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.thisptr.natoms

    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            cdef np.ndarray res = np.zeros([self.thisptr.natoms,3], dtype=np.float)
            cdef int i
            for i in range(self.natoms):
                res[i][0] = self.thisptr.x[i][0]
                res[i][1] = self.thisptr.x[i][1]
                res[i][2] = self.thisptr.x[i][2]
            return res
            #return [ (self.thisptr.x[j][0],self.thisptr.x[j][1],self.thisptr.x[j][2])  for j in xrange(self.natoms)]

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    def next(self):
        return self.thisptr.next()
```

Comment: did you try numpys frombuffer function?

Answer (score 2):

1. Define the type of res:

   ```
   cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] res = ...
   ```
2. Use full index:

   ```
   res[i,0] = ...
   ```
3. Turn off boundscheck & wraparound

   ```
   @cython.boundscheck(False)
   @cython.wraparound(False)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what HYRY said and to ensure Cython can generate fast indexing code, try something like the following:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


ctypedef np.float_t ftype_t
cdef extern from "ccxtc.h" namespace "ccxtc":
    cdef cppclass xtc:
        xtc(char []) except +
        int next()
        int natoms
        float (*x)[3]
        float time


cdef class pyxtc:
    cdef xtc *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, char fname[]):
        self.thisptr = new xtc(fname)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    property natoms:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.thisptr.natoms

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    cdef _ndarray_from_x(self):
        cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] res = np.zeros([self.thisptr.natoms,3], dtype=np.float)
        cdef int i
        for i in range(self.thisptr.natoms):
            res[i,0] = self.thisptr.x[i][0]
            res[i,1] = self.thisptr.x[i][1]
            res[i,2] = self.thisptr.x[i][2]
        return res

    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._ndarray_from_x()

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    def next(self):
        return self.thisptr.next()
```

All I did was put the fast stuff inside a `cdef` method, put the right optimizing decorators on it, and called that inside the property's `__get__()`.  You should also make sure to refer to `self.thisptr.natoms` inside the `range()` call rather than use the `natoms` property, which has *lots* of Python overhead associated with it.